# defining an unusual 2-D array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to reference the 1st Dimension of a 2 Dimensional array using an enum. However, the configurations that each enum value represents sometimes overlap (not in any patterned way), meaning the data in the array will sometimes be the same. I therefore would like to have some elements point to the same array of data, as in the diagram below.

[image: unusual array config]

Is there any way of doing this at declaration-time in C++?

Comment: I'd suggest going with a table lookup system. Hava an array with values and have an array of references. the references access the corresponding values in the 1 dimensional array no matter how many times and that way you can copy things indefinately without having to worry about duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can build an array like that using an array of pointers; you will be able to reference elements in that array as if it were a regular 2D array. Here is an example:

```
enum MyEnum {
    enumFirst = 0
,   enumSecond = 1
,   enumSecondShared = 2
,   enumThird = 3
};

static int enumFirstData[] = {1, 2, 3};
static int enumSecondData[] = {4, 3, 2};
static int enumThirdData[] = {9, 7, 8};

int *enumData[] = {
    enumFirstData
,   enumSecondData
,   enumSecondData // <== Shared
,   enumSecondData
};
```

Now you can reference elements of this array like this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != 3 ; i++) {
    cout << enumData[enumSecondShared][i] << endl;
}
```

Since you are using C++, using `std::vector` or `std::array` is a preferred way of making collections. You can use the same trick as above to establish shared collection elements.

Answer (score 1):

you can define your own container type and use switch/case to map from the enums to the references. that way, you map those enums at declaration time, can use arbitrary enum values, and are more type safe than indexing an array of pointers.

it would look somehow like this (not tested), which specializes the `std::map` class:

```
template<class V>
class map<myenum,V>{
  V r1,r2,r3;
public:
  inline map(){}
  inline r1& operator[](myenum e){
    switch(e)
    {
    case E1: return r1;
    case E2:
    case E3: return r2;
    case E4:
    case E5: return r3;
    }
  }
}

map<myenum,vector<int>> example;
```

(sorry for not writing high-quality std-template style definitions, i'm not that used to program in c++ anymore.)

Answer (score 0):

All you need is just `std::map<your_enum_t, data_t*>`
You should feel mapping according to your needs